# Anylogic 7. Databases modelling

Tags: database, distributed, modeling, anylogic

I am looking for the best way to model a database system.
It should be made of nodes, edges and data query flows.
I know there is a flow lib, but i dont sure that it is usable for such things.
So, the question is: is there any libs that i could use for this purpose? Or i should mostly use my own types, agents etc.?

Comment: what do you mean by "model a database system".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fuild library (if you meant that) is not useful for that purpose.

If you want to model the flow of data through a system of nodes, you might want to start with a simple process-modelling approach where data items are agents flowing through queues, delays and service objects...

However, depending on what your database system is doing (I am no expert there), you might actually need to switch to a pure agent-based approach sooner or later (i.e. replace the process library objects with your own functionality).

In short: start with process modelling and introduce agent-based functionality over time...

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to AnyLogic I suggest you follow the logic in the tutorial for [agent based modeling](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_RoadTraffic%2Ftutorial%2FTutorial.html). Look at it as if the distributor is your server, the retailers your clients and the orders your queries. You can use GIS maps if you are concerned about the real location of servers and clients or use other network capabilities (or agent connections) if the actual locations are not important in your model.